# Negate existing knex where clause in query builder

Tags: knex.js

I have a knex QueryBuilder object `qb` that contains a number of `where` clauses. I would like to be able to wrap the entire where clause in a not statement effectively negating the entire where clause.

Example:

```
const qb = knex.queryBuilder();
qb.whereIn('name', ['alice', 'bob']);

// ... in some other part of the file ...

// Example of what I would like to do, effectively negate the above query if
// some condition is met.
if (negateSearch) {
    const outerQb = knex.queryBuilder();
    outerQb.whereNot(qb);
    // execute outerQb
} else {
    // execute qb
}
```

This should result in a query that looks like

```
where not (name in ('alice', 'bob'))`
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not currently supported by `knex`.

In the future, with this feature one could probably achieve that by having where clause stored separately from rest of the query builder https://github.com/tgriesser/knex/issues/1893

So right now you need to change your code that uses `knex` to not actually build the where clause until you know if it should be negated or not.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what do you want, you can use modify:

```
knex('table')
.whereIn('name', ['alice', 'bob']);
.modify((query) => {
  if (negateSearch) {
    query.whereNot('yourcondition')
  }
})
.orderBy('anyColumn', 'desc')
```

It will add the 'whereNot' condition only if negateSearch was true.